# What patents are being used by Lodsys to go after small iOS developers?

Tags: litigation, us7222078, us7620565, lodsys

What patents are being used by the patent troll Lodsys LLC to go after small iOS developers who take advantage of Apple's in-app purchase functionality?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I'm afraid it's difficult to determine what you are asking since you didn't link to a patent or include a patent number as a tag. Please help us understand what you're asking so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/04/patent-troll-lodsys-sues-10-mobile-game-makers-despite-apples-intervention/), Lodsys has filed a lawsuit claiming that charter.com, lampsplus.com, corbisimages.com and shop.nordstrom.com infringe upon the following two patents:

- Methods and systems for gathering information from units of a commodity across a network ([US7222078](http://www.google.com/patents/US7222078))
- Customer-based product design module ([US7620565](http://www.google.com/patents/US7620565))

Recently, Lodsys has filed further lawsuits against mobile gaming companies including Gameloft and Gamevil, citing patent infringement on those same two patents.

Answer (score 0):

Lodsys has [four patents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodsys#Patents):

- U.S. Patent [5,999,908](http://www.google.com/patents/US5999908) (The "908" patent) "Customer-based product
  design module"
- U.S. Patent [7,133,834](http://www.google.com/patents/US7133834) (The "834" patent) "Product Value Information Interchange Server"
- U.S. Patent [7,222,078](http://www.google.com/patents/US7222078) (The "078" patent) "Methods and Systems for Gathering Information from Units of a Commodity Across a Network"
- U.S. Patent [7,620,565](http://www.google.com/patents/US7620565) (The
  "565" patent) "Customer-based product design module"

Comment: Never seen a more baloney title, "Customer-based product design module" !!!